# Why does the word "repose" not have sense of "re"(again) in it?

Tags: prefixes

I just looked for the definition of "repose". It was defined as

to place (confidence, trust, etc.) in someone or something

Now I'm pondering over why does the definition not include the sense of "re" (again) in it. Is it because it's not a hard and fast rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, regarding prefixes: no, the presence of the prefix does not always mean the word is using that prefix. In this case, it looks like definition creep.

There are several other definitions I found for "repose," mainly having having to do with resting. Physically setting an object down is one of them, and it could be possible that the "trust" definition emerged from that (the definition creep.) However there's no evidence I could find so don't take this too seriously.